# Rate and proportion in formulating a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In writing differential equations I don't understand the difference of rate and proportion.

Say I have two compartments, `A` and `B`. A certain proportion of items in compartment `A`, move to compartment `B` at a rate $k$.

When writing the differential equation for the rate of change in compartment `B`, should it be ${dB \over dt}= kA$ or ${dB \over dt}= \alpha kA$, where $\alpha$ is the proportion of items that moves from A to B.

Does the rate, $k$, include the proportion that moves that I don't have to include the proportion explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first notation is correct.

second is to be used when question mentions **proportional to the rate**

Also, $\frac{dB}{dT}=-\frac{dA}{dT}=kA$